# $imagick->readImage() timeout error for large pdf

Tags: php

I am trying to read a pdf file with imagick and split it into images. The program is stopping its execution due to a timeout error. The pdf is quite large - over 600MB. is there a workaround to this?

```
$imagick->readImage($pdfFile);
```

Comment: A 600 MB file is not suitable for a web application. Even 6MB would be quite large for a PDF, what's in it?

Comment: I have images pertaining to a book published by the company I work with

Comment: simply change your php timeout value and re-try

Comment: Why do you load this into Imagick? What's the big plan?